# Plot densities from a list of Bootstrap data

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I am working with R and seeking assistance with creating a bootstrap sample from my data and plotting the density of the sampled data along with the actual data. Here's the code to produce the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

historical_tuition <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-03-10/historical_tuition.csv')  

tuition_df <- historical_tuition %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type,
              values_from = tuition_cost
              ) %>%
  na.omit() %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

# Set set.seed a starting number to generate a sequence of random numbers so that we can get reproducible results
set.seed(123)
tuition_boot <- bootstraps(tuition_df,
                          times = 1e3,
                          apparent = FALSE)
```

The bootstrap data is saved as a list. I would like to visualize the distribution of the bootstrapped samples of all_institutions alongside the actual data's density plot. The final output should look like this: [image]

Any suggestions or guidance on the plotting part would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So you have a vector of values and you want to plot densities of a group of random samples of an unspecified size and superimpose  the density for the entire set?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a plot like you describe for example with:

```
library(tidyverse)

historical_tuition <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-03-10/historical_tuition.csv')

tuition_df <- historical_tuition %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = type,
    values_from = tuition_cost
  ) %>%
  na.omit() %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()

set.seed(123)

rsample::bootstraps(tuition_df, times = 1e3, apparent = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(dat_boot = purrr::map(
      .x = splits,
      .f = function(split) { rsample::analysis(split) }
      )) %>% 
  select(id, dat_boot) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(dat_boot)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = all_institutions, group = id, color = "color_1")) +
  geom_density(
    aes(x = all_institutions, color = "color_2"),
    data = tuition_df
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(color_1 = "grey70", color_2 = "red"),
    labels = c(color_1 = "bootstrapped", color_2 = "original")
    ) +
  theme_light()
```